# iterate using yield of a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7

Suppose we have this dictionary and I need to walk through its branches and yields everything found in files

```
a={'files': {'file root':'some root path', 'other file': 'other path'}, 
   'directories':{'directory1':{'files':{'file1':'some path'}, 
                                'directories':{'directory2':{'files':{}, 
                                                             'directories': {}}}}, 
                  'folder1':{'files':{}, 
                             'directories':{'folder2': {'files': {}, 
                                                        'directories': {}}, 
                                            'archive1':{'files': {'empty':None}, 
                                                        'directories':{}}}}} }
```

my implementation looks like this

```
def walk_directory_files(directory):
    directories = dict.__getitem__(directory, 'directories')
    files       = dict.__getitem__(directory, 'files')
    for f in files:
        yield f
    for k,d in dict.items(directories):
        walk_directory_files(d)

def walk_files(D):
    return walk_directory_files(D)

# now lets try it
list(walk_files(a))
>> ['other file', 'file root']
```

I am not sure why walk_directory_files within the loop is not called !!!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please describe the problem more detailled.

Comment: Why the `dict.__getitem__()` call instead of just using `get()`, why the extra function `walk_files()`?

Comment: yes you are right, I copied my code as it is. in my implementation the dictionary a is protected for some reason. so i have to use __getitem__.
I know its a stupid layer of protection but to avoid direct overwriting a key

Comment: I wonder why would someone rate the question down ! was it necessary really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to recursively yield.

```
for k,d in dict.items(directories):
    for e in walk_directory_files(d):
        yield e
```

Note that Python 3.3 [adds additional syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) specifically for this:

```
for k,d in dict.items(directories):
    yield from walk_directory_files(d) # Python 3.3+ only!
```

Comment: thanks, now it is working ! shouldn't the yield in the the loop on files suffice? Before asking the question I put print directory in beginning of walk_directory_files but walk_directory_files(d) was  not printing anything as if it was not calling the function at all